# Postgres error: non-integer constant in ORDER BY

Tags: linux, postgresql, window

Running this query produces an error only on windows (psql v14 & v15) and runs fine on linux. Are there some settings that are causing this?

```sql
SELECT 1 ORDER BY TRUE;
```

To make it work on windows it needs casting:

```sql
SELECT 1 ORDER BY TRUE::BOOLEAN;
```

Comment: what is the case where you need an `ORDER BY true` ???

Comment: I am not trying to rewrite a query, I'm trying to understand and fix this platform related stability issue of a system

Comment: Please give the complete version (`select version()`) from both OS.

Comment: What is the error you get on Windows?